# Can't enable html input fields in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webview, safari

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hadaytullah/6pxdz7n1/9/) here. Starting with html elements in the below given structure, safari for some strange reason could not enable all input elements. It just enables the first one only. Might be some bug?

```
<fieldset disabled><div>

    <div><fieldset disabled>
        <input type="text" disabled>
    </fieldset></div>

    <div><fieldset disabled>
        <input type="text" disabled>
    </fieldset></div>

</div></fieldset>
```

Javascript here:

```
$('fieldset').prop('disabled',false);
$("input").prop('disabled',false);
```

Comment: maybe try $.each() function http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: I assigned an id to the second input field and then using jquery I have tried to directly enable it but it didn't work.

Comment: I think in real life you don't have disable both fieldset and input. It is enough to just put disable on top fieldset. Furthermore the disable option for fieldset is not supported in IE or Safari 6 and earlier versions.. Input on the other hand is fully supported.

Comment: Could you provide me a link where Safari documentation states that 'disabled' is not supported on fieldset? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_fieldset_disabled.asp

Comment: Thanks! BTW I am testing with safari 9.

Answer (score 1):

To make Safari correctly enable all inputs you should enable all fieldset **from the inside out**, so the nested ones first:

```
const fieldsets = document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
Array.from(fieldsets).reverse().forEach(fieldset => fieldset.disabled = false);
```

[Complete codepen](https://codepen.io/bennystijn/pen/MWgxXLp) with some an extra use case with fieldsets.

This was tested on Safari 13.0. This is definitely a bug and I will report it to Apple.